# ¿Cómo imprimir un día que no es el de hoy?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando obtener la fecha actual más 5 días.

```
$fechaactual2 = Date("Y-m-d");
$entrega_mas_cinco = DATE_ADD('$fechaactual2',INTERVAL 5 DAY);
echo $entrega_mas_cinco;
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> syntax error, unexpected '4' (T_LNUMBER)

¿Por qué no imprime?

Comment: Lo primero que se me ocurre es que deberias quitarle las comillas simples a `$fechaactual2` dejandolo tal que: `DATE_ADD($fechaactual2,INTERVAL 5 DAY);`

Comment: nada sigue el error syntax error, unexpected '5' (T_LNUMBER)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Me parece que `DATE_ADD` es una función de SQL.</s>

[`date_add`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-add.php) es un *alias*  del método `add` de la clase `DateTime`. El problema que veo es que al usar [`Date`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php), no estás creando un objeto `DateTime`, por lo tanto no puedes usar ninguno de los métodos relativos a ese objeto.

En PHP conviene que trabajes con [la clase **`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) en todo lo que tenga que ver con fechas / horas. Cuando creas un objeto `DateTime`, luego le puedes aplicar cualquiera de los métodos de que dispone, entre los cuales se encuenta `add`, para añadir períodos a ese objeto. Y lo puedes combinar con otras clases como `DateInterval`. Puedes trabajar las zonas horarias, hacer cualquier tipo de cálculo, etc, etc. O sea, toda la potencia de un objeto real y no de una simple cadena que es lo que te crea `Date`.

Otra cosa, conviene usar siempre los formatos para la salida (impresión). No tiene mucho sentido crear un objeto formateado (eso es como pretender que una persona nazca siendo ya adulta :)). Deja que el sistema cree el objeto de la forma más sencilla posible y dale formato sólo cuando lo necesites, es decir, al imprimirlo.

Otra ventaja es que te permite usar un estilo de programación orientado a objetos, que es mucho más claro, elegante e intuitivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
$fecha = new DateTime();
$fecha->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
```

Salida:

```
2018-11-04
```

---

Como prueba, vamos a escribir lo mismo, usando los *alias* de que dispones para escribirlo con el estilo por procedimientos:

```
$fecha = date_create(); //equivale a new DateTime()
date_add($fecha, date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 days')); //add->(new DateInterval
echo date_format($fecha, 'Y-m-d'); //->format
```

La salida será la misma, pero el primer código es más elegante, intuitivo y fácil de comprender.

Comment: Es una funcion de sql pero tambien existe en PHP: [ejemplos](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/date_interval_create_from_date_string/php-date_interval_create_from_date_string-function-examples.html).
Lo que esta mal formulada. Tal y como sugiere el link podria utilizar `date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 days')` para crear el intervalo

Comment: @Txema la función [`date_interval_create_from_date_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-interval-create-from-date-string.php), aparte de lo fea que es, laaarga como ella sola, no es otra cosa que un *alias* de uno de los métodos de la clase `DateInterval`. Conviene si es posible pasar a la POO, pues el código es mucho más claro y más fácil.

Comment: Sin duda, a pesar de que existe la funcion que nombra el autor, es recomendable usar la clase `DateInterval` para tener un codigo más limpio.

Comment: Correcto ntzz. He actualizado la respuesta dando más detalles gracias al comentario de @Txema.